# SplFixedArray использовать для хранения данных запроса

Tags: php

Прочитал про "жирные" массивы PHP и захотел использовать SplFixedArray для хранения больших массивов с данными из SQL запроса.

```
for($i = 0, $cnt = count($rows_); $i < $cnt; $i++)
{
    $array[$rows_[$i]['analiz_id']] = ['id' => $rows_[$i]['analiz_id'], 'name' => $rows_[$i]['name'], 'template' => $rows_[$i]['template_id']];
}  
$array = SplFixedArray::fromArray($array, false);
```

есть ли большой смысл преобразовывать полученные запросом данные в фиксированный массив? или это лишняя операция?

Comment: Вопрос-то в чем?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Использовать SplFixedArray имеет смысл в том случае, если в массиве очень много записей (более 30 000). При этом размер длины строки не имеет значения. В оф. документации очень наглядные [примеры](http://php.net/manual/ru/class.splfixedarray.php) в комментариях.

Answer (score 2):

Первое, о чем стоит подумать - какая именно проблема решается? Курить мануалы и повышать свою квалификацию - это замечательно, но непосредственно микрооптимизацию требуют знаний, *где закопаны тела* и сравнительные бенчмарки на всех объемах данных (никто же не хочет упереться в то, что оптимизированный кусок кода, который ускоряет выполнение в два раза на массиве в 100000 элементов, проседал в восемь раз по скорости при 10000 обработках по 10 элементов, верно?). Поэтому, если в данный момент все работает *терпимо*, и нет времени на полноценное исследование, можно спокойно *оставить как есть* - не факт, что оптимизируется нужный участок кода, не факт, что эта оптимизация сработает, не факт, что она вообще нужна.

Если же приложение действительно тормозит, то тут нужно проводить профилирование и выяснять, что и почему оттормаживается. Чаще всего это все-таки база данных - она, кроме редких исключений, читает данные с диска, и временные затраты на эту операцию обычно в разы больше, чем на обработку этих данных. Кроме того, есть еще много узких мест в классическом приложении - например, блокирующие сессиии или чтение интерпретируемых файлов - которые могут изрядно подпортить жизнь в скорострельности. Поэтому, опять же, оптимизация должна начинаться с профилирования.

Профилирование самых привычных узких мест, как правило, предоставляет сам фреймворк - в нем можно посмотреть время выполнения запросов к базе данных, время на рендеринг страниц и прочее. Если этого не хватает - можно взять xDebug, и с его помощью построить полное дерево вызовов, которое отобразит врея выполнение каждой функции и метода в одном запросе к приложению. В то же время, хорошее приложение будет постоянно писать в лог, в котором можно будет визуально определить сильно расходящиеся временные метки.

Когда после этого наконец находится узкое место, не стоит торопиться просто менять структуры данных. В данном случае *принципиально* алгоритм не меняется - используется все тот же массив, просто в другом исполнении. Несмотря на то, что нижележащая имплементация может заметно влиять на производительность, здесь, скорее всего, она идентична за исключением некоторых поправок, да и вряд ли она даст сильный выигрыш для всего приложения. Скорее всего, можно значительно оптимизировать время выполнения за счет оптимизации базы данных (вплоть до перехода с модели *pull-on-demand* к *push-on-change* - когда результат сложных выборок подготавливается при обновлении данных, а не при уже необходимости запросить результат сложный выборки - или вообще смены движка на распределенное решение, которое будет наращивать скорость за счет количества узлов), кэширования (если сервер один, то можно вообще использовать какое-нибудь in-memory решение, хотя и любой сетевой сервис на том же серваке будет работать просто молниеносно) и перехода на асинхронные обработки (например, подготовку тех же сложных результатов фоновыми рабочими процессами).

Что до перехода непосредственно с одной имплементации массивов на другую. Я не берусь рассказывать внутреннее устройство привычного массива PHP, потому что я его не знаю, но так или иначе внутри поддерживается связка key-value, и для нахождения value сначала надо найти key. Даже если эта связка идентична HashMap в Java (там применяются некоторые хитрости, чтобы не приходилось итерировать списки key, и чтобы вообще эти списки вырождались в одно значение), то переход от ассоциативного массива zval - zval (zvalue - C-контейнер для всех значений в PHP) к просто списку типа vector (в котором *скорее всего* доступ к элементам осуществляется за счет простого подсчета точного указателя в памяти) "убьет" ряд операций, необходимых для получения значения в простом PHP-массиве (и, наверняка, снизит нагрузку на память - скорее всего, разработчики преследовали именно эту цель, нежели ускорение обработки). В то же время, реализация в виде класса внедряет дополнительный оверхед (например, для вызова нижележащего C-API будет производиться минимум на один вызов метода больше, а это относительно дорогая операция), поэтому в этом решении наличиствуют как плюсы, так и минусы, ***реальное воздействие которых очень сложно просчитать заранее, и, более того, это реальное воздействие теоретически - теоретически! - может быть разным на разных платформах и машинах***. Поэтому для принятия взвешенного решения здесь нужно читать, *где зарыты тела* (фактически - сам С-код PHP и пояснения разработчиков ядра), проводить бенчмарки, или, как минимум, спрашивать гугл о бенчмарках других людей - как, например, сделал предыдущий отвечающий. В общем же случае не стоит тратить время на оптимизацию участков кода, которые не вызывают заметных для человека тормозов приложения.